# get geolocation ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, geolocation, ionic-framework

I'm working on an application in many parts I need to get the user's current location. This works especially well for me but today I have a little problem. In the home of my application I also need to get this information so that you use the same function that I use in my application

```
    function success(pos) {
      $scope.latitud = pos.coords.latitude
      $scope.longitud =  pos.coords.longitude;
    }

    function error(err) {
      alert("El servicio de GPS en tu dispositivo esta desactivado.");
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,error)
```

What I need is to know that data each time you enter in this view but I could not do it, try as in many other parts of my project use:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){

})
```

But it does not work, plus I need you when loading the view or enter it fully, an action, which occupies these geolocation data and connects to my server to run.

```
      $http({method: 'GET', url: URL_BASE+'viewsCercanos/'+sessionService.get("user_id")+'/'+sessionService.get("hash")+"/"+$scope.latitud+"/"+$scope.longitud})
      .success(function(data){
        if(data.Count > 0){
          //SOLO TRES
          $scope.views = data.View;
          $scope.mostrar_mensaje = false;
        }else{
          $scope.mostrar_mensaje = true;
          $scope.mensaje = "No tienes views en tus registros."
        }
      })
      .error(function(){

      })
      .finally(function(){
        $scope.hide();
      });
```

But at the time when the action is executed the latitude and longitude values are undefined after print run values and if they are seteados accordingly. This order I use it in various parts of my application and everything works fine, but in this particular case, I guess may be that the view is the main must be something more to manage to load these values before or during load .